# Front camera is not supported

Tags: card.io

The function CardIOActivity.canReadCardWithCamera(this) and the class CardIOActivity itself does not provide a way to allow people working with front camera. Can this option be provided?

Answer (score 0):

We (card.io) experimented quite a bit with using the front camera (including mirrored output and not) and found it to be an awkward and uncomfortable user experience, so we made a conscious decision not to enable it.

Comment: Have you experimented on tablets? Unlike phones the screen won't be covered by credit card and they are usually put on a flat surface. I find it is very difficult to carry a tablet and calibrate the device to rectangular credit card area. In addition, some affordable tablets such as Nexus 7 only have front camera.

Comment: @Polymorpher we played with the iPad a lot. We haven't spent as much time with the many Android tablets out there; we know we're a bit spotty on that front, and are planning to revisit that more closely at some point.

Comment: Are there any plans to support front facing cameras in the future? just like @Polymorpher , I think for  tablets (iPads for me) used as kiosks this would be **very** useful.

Comment: As a general rule, libraries should allow the user to choose (in this case, front or back camera) instead of making assumptions about what "makes sense" or doesn't.  A kiosk tablet is a valid use case for the front camera.